# Start Ruby on Rails app through systemd socket activation (i.e. start Rails server listening on pre-existing socket)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, systemd

As the title states, I'm trying to start a Ruby on Rails app through systemd socket activation. I've no prior experience with Ruby and the lack of quality documentation is frustrating.

Obtaining the listen socket from systemd is trivial enough, though I'm struggling to put that socket to use. Is there an app server, that accepts a pre-existing listen socket? Or do I have to write my own, possibly by implementing a Rack::Handler (going by what limited information I've been able to gather from the documentation)? In the latter case a minimal example implementation would be helpful.

I'm looking for a production-suitable, lightweight, least-effort solution, capable of serving an average of 2 concurrent users on embedded hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Puma 3.0.0, socket activation is supported by its Rack module, which is used by `rails server`. This means that running `bin/rails server puma` from systemd with socket activation will now work out of the box (tested with Puma 3.9.1). One caveat is that you must start `bin/rails` inside your application root, not the globally installed version.

For more details on this setup and some examples, see [my blogpost](http://www.stderr.nl/Blog/Software/Rails/RailsSocketActivation.html).

Answer (score 0):

In absence of any alternatives, I'll likely end up using the [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) web server, <s>which implements the systemd socket activation protocol</s>.

EDIT: Puma does implement socket activation, but not in the Rack handler.
I arrived at my initial conclusion via `grep -r LISTEN_FDS` and only discovered my mistake once I actually tried it.

Comment: It seems this was fixed in Puma v3.0.0, see the [commit](https://github.com/puma/puma/commit/d6df5cec224a9a020dfb262a5d4c1b52d33e6df3) and my [blogpost](http://www.stderr.nl/Blog/Software/Rails/RailsSocketActivation.html) about setting this up.